# Erro de sintaxe em SELECT, no PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou colocando o seguinte código para fazer uma consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY coluna WHERE ROWNUM = 5
```

Porém, ao colocar isso em meu PHP, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ROWNUM = 2' at line 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WHERE` vem antes de `ORDER BY`

`SELECT * FROM tabela  WHERE ROWNUM = 5 ORDER BY coluna`

Comment: Obrigado. E não acredito que fiquei preso 10 minutos por causa dessa bobeira.

Comment: Nem eu. Mas acontece.

Comment: Aguardarei o tempo restante para poder aceitar a resposta. Obrigado novamente

Comment: As vezes é apenas um maldito parênteses de um `IF` não fechado na linha 200 que te tira o sono porquê quando o erro é acusado, acusa na linha 5340, `unexpected '{'`... AFF

Answer (score 5):

Sintaxe correta é:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE ROWNUM =5 ORDER BY coluna
```

Comment: Obrigado. Erro bobo que me custou tempo

Comment: Já fiz dessas tbm, hehe